# how to solve uiautomatorviewer Error taking device screenshot: EOF

Tags: android-uiautomator

I tried to search Google it, but I couldn't find a solution.
Somebody Help me!!

I've also deleted HXML.
Androy and the studio have been re-installed.
It has not been resolved.!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr3Ja.png)

Comment: How you are taking device screenshot?

Comment: Whats the error? Please elaborate more on it.

Comment: @SushantSomani added screenshot. click the link(enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue. change your adb.exe https://yonoo88.tistory.com/1273

you need downgrade adb.exe file

Replace adb.exe! to Android SDK Platform-Tools 26.0.2 version of adb.exe!